# What are the steps for migrating a Cassandra cluster in Azure to GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cassandra, migration, database-migration

I am planning to migrate Cassandra Cluster from Azure virtual machines to Google COmpute Engine. As as initial setup i have configured the VPN tunnel between both the environment and changed cassandra.yaml with new cluster details.

Please help me with required steps to achieve migration with zero downtime.

i have tried using sstableloader for migration but as there are multiple keyspaces creating schema's in google compute engine can be complex.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have connectivity from your on-prem to the cloud instance, you could do the following:

- add the cloud data center to your current cluster
- increase the replication factor to include the new dc
- run a repair
- when repair is complete you can cutover to the cloud dc
- remove the old dc from the replication factor
- decommission the old dc

These links may help:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html

Answer (score 0):

I echo @stevenlacerda's answer except I wouldn't run `nodetool repair` because it's an expensive operation. And since you've already built the cluster in GCP, you will not be able to just add them as a new DC.

As a prerequisite, you will need to tear down the GCP nodes and start from scratch. You can either choose to (a) uninstall Cassandra completely and delete the contents of all data + configuration directories, or (b) start with fresh EC2 instances.

If it were be, I would go with option (b) since it reduces the risk of human error if you missed to clear something out. A misstep means you run into weird errors trying to add the nodes in a new DC.

Either way, once you have [provisioned the nodes in a new DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html):

1. Add the new DC in GCP to the replication settings for all the relevant keyspaces.
2. Populate data on each node by running `nodetool rebuild -- azure_dc_name`.
3. Once all nodes have been rebuilt, point your application(s) to the new DC.

After you've verified that your application instance(s) is operational, you can remove the DC in Azure from replication and [decommission the DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html). Cheers!